# "Specified cast is not valid" when creating form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am new to programming and I am trying to create a program which will return the href links of a website. The links will then be displayed in a text box

I have created a backgroundworker for the code to run so that the program dosent freezes when extracting data, but however I got this error instead:

**"An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Specified cast is not valid."**

Would appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.BackgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)

End Sub



Private Sub BackgroundWorker2_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker2.DoWork



    Dim pageHTML As HtmlElementCollection = Me.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")

    For Each pageHREF As HtmlElement In pageHTML

        Dim picurl As String = pageHREF.GetAttribute("href").ToString
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & picurl & Environment.NewLine

    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Can you minimize the code so the problem still exists?

Comment: The point of a BackgroundWorker is to do the long running task in the DoWork method.  You are not supposed to refer to UI elements there

Comment: If you want to avoid locking up the user interface while you download and parse a webpage, look into using the "async" and "await" keywords that are available with .Net 4.5.  They make these types of tasks a lot easier to write.